# Cisco N9K-93180LC-EX port configurations

Tags: nx-os

i have two n9k-93180LC-EX in my stock and i need 10x 40G and 8x 100G QSFP28 ports, i want to configure them as VPC and configure them as 18x 40G/100G/QSFP28,
in the cisco website said it supports up to 18x 100G , Does it support 18x 40G/100G/QSFP28 natively? or should i use breakcout?